Is there a solution for getting rank value in Cooja Contiki when simulating a sinkhole attack?
I found a folder from GitHub Sinkhole simulation that shows the simulation process for the sinkhole simulation process. By following the steps given I could not get the rank value in the mote output window.
As the paper stated, I've inserted the 'malicious-udp-client-sinkhole.c' and 'malicious-udp-client-sinkhole.h' files into home/contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-udp folder. Then in 'home/contiki/core/net/rpl' the rpl-mhrof.c is replaced too. Makefile is implemented as well. Except the IDS step I do not replace the files, not sure if it's related.
Line 55 in rpl-mrhof.c
#include "/home/user/contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-udp/malicious-udp-client-sinkhole.h"

Mote output window
It does not show the rank value. I'm not sure if it's the directory issue that is correctly input in the rpl-mrhof.c file.
May I ask how do I get the rank value by implementing the rpl-mrhof.c file in the correct path successfully?
